# SharePoint IRM: Even author can't open document

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, rights-management

I've tried to implement RMS server and enable IRM on SharePoint to connect to this RMS. However, after enable IRM for a document library, I tested by uploading some documents and it turned out that nobody, even the document author   , has permission to view it. 
I tried to turn on User Profile and make it synced, however there problem persists.

The problem seems to come from SharePoint as I already test RMS server with Microsoft Office only and it still can restrict users normally without the same issue as in SharePoint

Please support

Error message

[image].

Document library

[image]

IRM setting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I did not the Read&Execute permission for the RMS application pool service account on ServerCertification.asmx